# jQuery CLICK event or .html not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#circle {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        background-color:blue;
        border-radius:100px;
        margin:10px;
    }
</style>

<script src="file:///C|/Users/Gopal/Desktop/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="circle"></div>
    <p>THIS IS A CIRCLE</p>
</body>

<script>
        $("#circle").click(function() { 
        $("p").hmtl("its changed");
        });

</script>

</html>
```

When I **click** on the circle I want the text below the circle to change to the one mentioned in my **$("p").hmtl("its changed");** But its not happening

Comment: Open the browser's error console. The error message should give a good hint about what's wrong.

Comment: its `html` not `hmtl`, function spelling in wrong

Comment: ["TypeError: $(...).hmtl is not a function "
Its not a function was the error] Thanks-Juhana

[Yes it worked I changed from "hmtl" to "html"
It worked]-Thanks Saptal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working sample of [FIDLLE](http://jsfiddle.net/maxspan/5qwzwd46/)

```
 <div id="circle">I am a circle</div>
    <p>THIS IS A CIRCLE</p>

$("#circle").click(function(){
    $("p").html("Changed");
});
```